# NSView drawrect flicker

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I am using NSView as a digital display screen.

When I invoke

```
[display setNeedsDisplay:YES]
```

The view's drawrect function seems to entirely clear the view before redrawing it contents.

This results in what appears as a "blinking" or "flickering" display.

Is there any way to alleviate this behavior?

I read about the concept of NSView layers, placing the most changing portions in one layer, while drawing seldom changing in another layer, but I was unable to find any concrete example code using layers.

Desired behavior:  drawrect draws contents without 1st clearing view.  After drawing, clears previous contents that does not intersect with new contents.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a custom `NSView` subclass that you've created? If so, we need to see its `drawRect:` method to be able to diagnose what might be causing the flickering.

Comment: Nice handle!  No.  It is not a custom NSView.  It is a small digital display which I use to display segmented digits with NSBezierPath.  These have been pre-drawn in the view and are transparent.  To display a segment.  I use the [segname fill] method.